# Json Parser with volley library

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I was searching a solution but I could not solve it.

thats my JSON

{"Error":"","Filme":[{
        "title": "Dawn of the Planet of the Apes",
        "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg",
        "rating": 8.3,
        "releaseYear": 2014,
        "genre": ["Action", "Drama", "Sci-Fi"]
    },
    {
        "title": "District 9",
        "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg",
        "rating": 8,
        "releaseYear": 2009,
        "genre": ["Action", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller"]
    },
...
...
}]}

and that's my code

```
// Movies json url
private static final String url = "https://d....url....";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private HorizontalListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView  = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url ,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();


                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(TAG_MOVIE);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                             //Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);





}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

but the result is only a white layout. I think it is because my code don't find "Filme" variable in JSON but i don't know how to fix it.

any idea??

Thank you!!

Comment: I use already JsonArrayRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Filme" is not a JSONObject, it is a JSONArray actually. Simply parse it as a JSONArray :-)

EDIT:

First of all, use a StringRequest, not JSONArray, as the root of what you receive is NOT an JSONArray.

And then, once you have a simple String as a result, do something like this:

```
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray films = root.getJSONArray("Filme");
        JSONObject obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < films.length(); i++) {
            obj = films.getJSONObject(i);

            //Put all the parsing for a single Movie JSONObject here
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I make it with volley?

Comment: JSONArray jsonArrayFilme = (your json).getJSONArray("Filme");

Comment: You mean Like this??
// Parsing json
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
try {
JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
Movie movie = new Movie();
//Filme is json array
JSONArray Arry = obj.getJSONArray("Filme");
ArrayList<String> Filme = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int j = 0; j < Arry.length(); j++) {
Filme.add((String) Arry.get(j));
}
movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
.doubleValue());
movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));
...

Comment: One more think. What if my JSON is like this:    

{"Error":"","Filme":[{ "title": "Dawn of the Planet of the Apes", "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg", "rating": 8.3, "releaseYear": 2014, "Langtext": "fdfdfd<br /><br />fdfggfg", ... ... }]}

the "Langtext" have some like HTML.

What can i make?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I made with “Kelevandos” help. 
Maybe it can help someone.

```
// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest movieReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
//Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
hidePDialog();

JSONObject root;
try {
root = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray films = root.getJSONArray("Filme");
JSONObject obj;
for (int i = 0; i < films.length(); i++) {
obj = films.getJSONObject(i);

//Put all the parsing for a single Movie JSONObject here

Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
.doubleValue());
movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

// Genre is json array
 JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
}
movie.setGenre(genre);

// adding movie to movies array
movieList.add(movie);
```

Comment: One more think. What if my JSON is like this: {"Error":"","Filme":[{ "title": "Dawn of the Planet of the Apes", "image": "api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg";, "rating": 8.3, "releaseYear": 2014, "Langtext": "fdfdfd<br /><br />fdfggfg", ... ... }]} the "Langtext" have some like HTML. What can i make?